# Why do we need two separate categories for "First Posts" and "Late Answers" in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queue

I just finished doing six reviews of "First Posts." However, when I clicked on the "recent reviews" link for that category, it showed zero reviews for me. I then clicked on the "recent reviews" link for "Late Answers," and my six reviews were tallied there instead.

This seems to happen fairly often. Also, when there are pending reviews under both categories, clearing one queue often partially or wholly clears the other queue as well.

It appears that there is not a very clear distinction between "Late Answers" and "First Posts," or at least that they are heavily overlapping categories. Both are for posts by new users. The fact that in one case it's a late answer to an earlier question and in other case it's an answer to a more recent question doesn't seem sufficient to have separate review queues.

Couldn't the two simply be merged together into a single category? What is the purpose of having two different categories, when in many cases the site architecture causes them to be interchangeable anyway?

Comment: Yes, there certainly is overlap. I think "late posts" is when someone under 300 rep or something answers a post that is 6 months or older. "First posts" is any new user's *first* post. "Low quality" posts are triggered by flagging, downvotes, and character minimums. I don't know all the specifics so this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Also, are you more interested in the specifics, a [tag:feature-request] to merge the two queues, or do you believe there is a [tag:bug]? I'd focus on just one.

Comment: @fredsbend I'm throwing stuff up in the air hoping to get some answers. I wouldn't want to make a feature request or bug report if there are good answers for why it is the way it is. If it turns out that it really *isn't* all that well thought out, and there *aren't* good answers, then it might be time to make a ruckus.

Comment: [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390)

Comment: I don't know the exact rep, but @fredsbend has the right idea. The late answers queue is probably most useful when you have a new user come and answer lots of questions before they understand how the site works - only one will show up in the first posts queue, but the rest will show up in the late answers queue.